# Unable to access full web service in Ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache2, virtualbox, openstreetmap

I got a Win10 host system and a virtualbox ubuntu 16.04 guest system.
The network is bridged and disabled the firewall in the ubuntu system.
I installed a Openstreetmap-Server (osm) after this:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04

It uses apache2 to serve the tiles over mod_tile. The rendering is fine.

The webfront ist umap (a package with leaflet) after this tutorial.

https://umap-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ubuntu/

The webfront runs over nginx and uwsgi.

In the Ubuntu guest system all is working fine.
I can access with Firefox the website and the rendering is fine.

When I want to access the website from the Win10 host system, the "normal" website ist fine, too. The part where the map should be is grey and gets not rendered. Why the access from the host system is only half working?

I cannot get it working outside the virtualbox, but why :(

Comment: Did you check the developer console of your browser for error messages?

Comment: yes, no errors, when I connect through FF in the vbox, apache access log shows a connection. from the windows host not, but why

Comment: Any pages that can not be found/have errors in your developer console, under 'Network'? An idea that I have: You are accessing the Ubuntu host from your Win10 browser, but the tile server URL points to `localhost`?